# Entity Framework code-first, one-to-zero-to-one and one-to-many relationship to same entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, code-first

I'm creating a code-first database with v6.0 of the Entity Framework. I have an **Organisation** class and a related **Location** class defined in c# as follows:

```
public class Organisation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }

    public int? HQLocationId { get; set; }
    public Location HQLocation { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }
    public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
}
```

As can be inferred from the classes, an **Organisation** can have multiple **Locations**, however it can only have one **Head Quarters Location**.

I'm using the Fluent API to configure the relationships between these classes.  The "multiple locations" aspect is simple enough and works with the following:

```
   HasMany(o => o.Locations)
      .WithRequired(o => o.Organisation)   
      .HasForeignKey(l => l.OrganisationId);
```

I cannot however seem to find the correct syntax to define the relationship that allows the HQ location to be defined.  If there a flaw in the approach I'm taking, or am I simply missing the right syntax?

**UPDATE**

If I add the following to the **Organisation** configuration:

```
   HasOptional(o => o.HQLocation)
      .WithMany()
      .HasForeignKey(o => o.HQLocationId)
      .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Then Entity Framework no longer errors and my data loads in a shape that suits my needs.

However this allows a **Location** to be the **HQ** for more than one **Organisation**; which ideally I do not want possible.

Comment: Did you solve it in the end?

Comment: No, the "Update" I added to the original post was the compromise I was left with when time ran out.

Answer (score 1):

In *one-to-one* or *one-to-zero or one* relationships `Id` should be same on both entities. This means that `Organisation.Id` must be same as `Location.Id` for `HQLocation`. And of course, it is not good design choice. What I recommend is to add property to `Location` to indicate whether it is a `HQLocation` or not:

```
public class Organisation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsHqLocation { get; set; }

    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }
    public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This solution is something I will consider if no other options present.  However it allows any number of Locations to be tagged as the HQ.  My design requirements are for only one HQ per organisation. This is therefore proposing a different design as opposed to answering the question. That said....it wasn't me that down-voted; I appreciate your suggestion.