# One to One and One to Many for the same entity type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to design the following entity relationship

- Program
- Assembly

A Program can have multiple assemblies. One of the assemblies will be a main assembly. Each assembly belongs to one program only.

The classes are modeled as follows:

```
public class Program
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual ProgramAssembly MainAssembly {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ProgramAssembly> Assemblies {get;set;}
}

public class ProgramAssembly
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual Program Program {get;set;}
   public int ProgramId {get;set;}
}
```

I am not specifying anything with the FluentApi (however, I have nothing against it).
With the code above, I get this error:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.
>
> InnerException: Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

I tried changing the ProgramAssembly to the following

```
public class ProgramAssembly
{
    [ForeignKkey("Program")]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual Program Program {get;set;}
}
```

However, then I get this error:

> ProgramAssembly_Program_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ProgramAssembly_Program_Source' in relationship 'ProgramAssembly_Program'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.

I also tried a following fluent API approach

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProgramAssembly>()
   .HasRequired(a => a.Program)
   .WithMany(p => p.Assemblies);

public class ProgramAssembly
    {        
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Program Program { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Program")] //same error with or without this attribute
        public int ProgramId { get; set; }
   }
```

Then the error is:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.'
>   UpdateException: Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

How do I allow that relationship without changing the approach to adding 'IsPrimary' attribute on Assembly?

I saw some similar questions on SO, but they were either about EF core, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49159604/ef-core-one-to-one-relation-on-to-many-relation-using-same-entity), or suggested significant logic change like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247771/entity-framework-code-first-one-to-zero-to-one-and-one-to-many-relationship-to), or even [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48445047/one-to-one-and-one-to-many-on-the-same-entity-in-entity-framework/48450058#48450058) that does not even compile.

Comment: How much can you change your model? I would think adding a `IsPrimary` property to `Assembly` is going to look better than having two relationships

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - thanks. I can do whatever I want with the model, however this approach is something I want to avoid. The reason is that I could end up with any number of Assemblies being set as Primary. Also, how would you see accessing the Primary Assembly of a Program?

Comment: You won't be able to do what you want by specifying the relations this way. In order to get something similar, you would need, like Camilo said, to add a "IsMain" property to the ProgramAssembly entity and if you want to get it inside the Program entity itself, you will need to change the MainAssembly property to "public ProgramAssembly MainAssembly {get { return Assemblies.where(asm => asm.IsMain).FirstOrDefault(); }}

Comment: That would be just `program.Assemblies.Single(x => x.IsMain)` (or you could even have it as a navigational property), but you are right that you would have to validate that upon saving. The answer for EF Core should work pretty much the same using the Fluent API. I am pretty sure you cannot do this through DataAnottations though

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - thanks. I tried the EF Core approach, only changing the 'HasOne' to 'HasRequired', but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you post what you tried (and the error if it changed)? The answer should be close to that

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - yes, updated the question

Comment: The thing is, you will need to say that the foreign key is `ProgramAssembly.Id` for the main assembly and `ProgramAssembly.ProgramId` for all other assemblies. Are you ok with that? (It certainly sounds awful to me)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - not sure what you mean, but I agree that this sounds weird.

Comment: I meant how the values are stored in the database. You cannot use one column for both the one-to-one and the one-to-many. That's why I suggested to have only one foreign key and a IsMain column

Comment: Any solution to the original question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to inform EF how your primary and foreign keys work. You need to add attributes to define your primary keys `[Key]` and define foreign keys and add attributes to your navigation properties to define the field that is the foreign key.

```
public class Program
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int MainAssemblyId {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("MainAssemblyId ")]
    public virtual ProgramAssembly MainAssembly {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ProgramAssembly> Assemblies {get;set;}
}

public class ProgramAssembly
{
   [Key]
   public int Id {get;set;}
   [ForeignKey("ProgramId")]
   public virtual Program Program {get;set;}
   public int ProgramId {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Hmm, so far that code gives me this exception:
`Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.ProgramAssemblies_dbo.Programs_ProgramId' on table 'ProgramAssemblies' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.`

Answer (score 0):

Below code will fulfill your requirement.

```
public class Program
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ProgramAssembly> Assemblies {get;set;}
}

public class ProgramAssembly
{
   public int Id {get;set;}

   [ForeignKey("ProgramId")]
   public virtual Program Program {get;set;}
   public int ProgramId {get;set;}
   public bool IsMainProgramAssembly
}
```

You can use `[Required]` for `ProgramId` if you need it or you can make `ProgramId` as nullable also.